# Modify the first letter of an argument in a user snippet in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I am using the prefix `prop` to generate:

```java
private $1 $2;
public void set$2($1 $2) {
    this.$2 = $2;
}
public $1 get$2() {
    return $2;
}
```

---

This is my snippet:

```json
"Add a property" : {
    "prefix": "prop",
    "body": [
        "private $1 $2;",
        "public $1 get$2() {",
        "\treturn $2;",
        "}",
        "public void set$2($1 $2) {",
        "\tthis.$2 = $2;",
        "}"
    ],
    "description": "Add a property to class"
}
```

---

Output:

```java
private int age;
public int getage() {
    return age;
}
public void setage(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}
```

---

Expected output:

```java
private int age;
public int getAge() {
    return age;
}
public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}
```

What do I change in my snippet to achieve this output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
"Add a property" : {
  "prefix": "prop",
  "body": [
    "private $1 $2;",
    "public $1 get${2/(.)/${1:/capitalize}/}() {",
    "\treturn $2;",
    "}",
    "public void set${2/(.)/${1:/capitalize}/}($1 $2) {",
    "\tthis.$2 = $2;",
    "}"
  ],
  "description": "Add a property to class"
}
```

This part `${2/(.)/${1:/capitalize}/}` will transform the 2nd tabstop.  It captures only the first character `(.)` of that word (`age` in your case)  in capture group 1 and then `${1:/capitalize}` will capitalize whatever is in capture group 1.

Have a look at snippet [variable transforms](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_variable-transforms).

[image: capitalize snippet transform demo]

Comment: Nope, still the same output.

Comment: I tested it of course before I posted it.  I added a gif showing it working - did you copy/paste my answer precisely?

Comment: Actually, yes! I guess I must have done something wrong :(

Comment: Definitely, I'll try it out today itself. Though I have a feeling, I may just as well go ahead and accept it :)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not on my normal computer, but try this:

```
"Add a property" : {
"prefix": "prop",
"body": [
    "private $1 $2;",
    "public $1 get${2:/capitalize/g}() {",
    "\treturn $2;",
    "}",
    "public void set${2:/capitalize/g}($1 $2) {",
    "\tthis.$2 = $2;",
    "}"
    ],
    "description": "Add a property to class"
}
```

Comment: [The Output](https://imgur.com/a/YjrdobZ)